# PHP Classes, Using a Query function in another PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

I have two class files: one is called class.database.php, and it is used solely for any functions that have to be done on the database (connect, disconnect, query, etc.)

This is class.database.php:

```
<?php
  class DATABASE
  {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->getConnected();
    }

    public function getConnected() {
        $dbHost = "localhost";
        $dbUser = "tysonmoyes";
        $dbPassword = "F!lmtrepid";
        $db = "tysonmoyes";

        $dbConn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $db);
        $this->dbConn = $dbConn;
    }

    function queryDB($queryString) {
        return mysqli_query($this->getConnected(), $queryString);
    }

    public function close() {
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }
  }
?>
```

My second class file is called class.users.php, and it handles all the information on a user account. It looks like this:

```
<?php
  include_once('config.php');
  class USER
  {
    private $conn;

    // All the variables needed for the user profile.
    public $username;
    public $userID;
    public $password;
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $emailAddress;
    public $address;
    public $city;
    public $province;
    public $country;
    var $myConn;

    function __construct($conn){
        $this->myConn = $conn;
    }

    function createNewUser($username, $password) {
        // Clean inputs
        $username = trim($username);
        $password =  trim($password);

        // Encrypt password
        $password = md5($password);

        // Check if username already exists
        $checkSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
        $checkResult = $this->myConn->queryDB($checkSQL);
        if($checkResult->num_rows > 0) {
            $error = "true";
            $errorMessage = "This username has already been taken. Please try again";
        }

        else {
            $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES('$username', '$password')";
            //$insertResult = $this->callDB()->query($insertSQL);

            // Get the user ID
            $userID = $this->insert_id;

            // Set the SESSION globals
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
        }

    }

    function login($username, $password) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' && password = '$password'";
        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
        $row = $this->conn->fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        $count = $this->conn->num_rows($result);
        if ($count == 1) {
            // Set Session Variables
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['userID'];

            return true;
        }
    }

    function isLoggedIn() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            return true;
        }

        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function redirect($url) {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    function logout() {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
    }
  }
?>
```

As you can see, the class.user.php calls a "config.php" file, which simply creates a new DATABASE and a new USER, using a link created from making a new DATABASE:

```
<?php
  // Turn on all error reporting
  ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  // Start Session
  session_start();

  // Set error to false, and blank error message
  $error = "false";
  $errorMessage = "";

  // Include Database info
  require_once('class.database.php');
  $link = new DATABASE();


  // Include User info
  require_once('class.user.php');

  // Create instance for user class
  $activeUser = new USER($link);
?>
```

Now, I'd like to focus on my queries, because none of them are working, and I understand why. The query function is in the DATABASE class, but $this is pointing to the USER class.

My question is: How should I write my query so that it properly calls the DATABASE class.

Also, before anyone mentions it, yes, I know md5 is a no-no, but this is for a class project that will be using mock user data, and our professor said that md5 was sufficient encryption for this project

EDIT: For the sake of this, could we focus on the createNewUser function in class.user.php? That's the part I'm currently playing with.

Comment: Why don't you just inherit (extend) your Database class in your Users class?

Comment: Rohit, the correct formatting for that would be:  class USER extend DATABASE, correct?

Comment: `class USER extends DATABASE`  in that case you don't need this `// Include Database info
  require_once('class.database.php');
  $link = new DATABASE();`

Comment: Your login is not using the right connection, you should be using `$this->myConn` not `$this->conn` from what I can see.

Comment: Also, why are you using `var $myConn;` and not just store that in the public/protected/private realm of the class?

Comment: And why not just store all the rest of your public user-based variables into an array so you don't have to keep adding variables when you want to store another variable?

Comment: Also, make sure to check for mysql errors, you don't seem to have any notification of failed mysql statements, even just for testing purposes. Also check that `$this->myConn` is an instance of `DATABASE`.

Comment: Lastly your `$this->dbConn` needs to be returned in your `getConnected()` method. This is likely the main culprit as to why your connection doesn't work.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: It also looks like you're writing your own super buggy, SQL exploitable ORM and that's not a very good idea. Have a look at things like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) to see if any of those would do a better job.

Comment: "our professor said that md5 was sufficient encryption for this project". Well, your professor is teaching you nonsense. The built-in [`password_hash`](http://php.net/function.password-hash) function is the *minimal* thing you should use for this, and it's actually less code to use properly. Even mentioning MD5, which was cracked twenty years ago, is exceptionally misguided. There is **no excuse** to not teach people proper hashing procedures. This takes all of five minutes to figure out since there's literally two functions to understand.

Comment: Believe me tadman, I wish I had a better prof for this class. She should NOT be teaching a data management course.

Comment: rasclatt, I've managed to get the insert working properly now; however, I can't seem to get the insert_id to report the proper number. 

The code I have for it right now:  `$userID = $this->conn->getConnected()->insert_id;` but this just returns 0.

Comment: Did you reassign `$this->myConn = $conn;` to `$this->conn = $conn;`? Is that the new connection variable?

Comment: Yes, I removed myConn altogether, and stuck with conn

Comment: I think the problem is that your main database class is a wee-bit wonky. You need to rework that class. It's not logical and may be not working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why, not to make a database connection link oncе. Without using method getConnected everytime to make new connection to db?

And what is $this->connection in method close of class DATABASE, perhaps, it must be a connection link.

```
  class DATABASE
  {
    protected $dbConn; //connection link

    protected static $dbHost = "localhost";
    protected static $dbUser = "tysonmoyes";
    protected static $dbPassword = "F!lmtrepid";
    protected static $db = "tysonmoyes";

    public function __construct() {
        $this->getConnected();
    }

    public function getConnected() {

        //if connection link allready exists return it;
        if(isset($this->dbConn)) {
            return $this->dbConn;
        }

        $this->dbConn = new mysqli(self::$dbHost, self::$dbUser, self::$dbPassword, self::$db);
        return $this->dbConn;
    }

    function queryDB($queryString) {
        return mysqli_query($this->getConnected(), $queryString);
    }

    public function close() {
        mysqli_close($this->dbConn);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The `return` in `__construct` - what is the point? I don't think it should be there

Comment: Ya, realy. @return statement must be in method getConnected (as it is called from __construct).

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to return you db connection link.

Database Class:

```
<?php
  class DATABASE
  {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->getConnected();
    }

    public function getConnected() {
        $dbHost = "localhost";
        $dbUser = "tysonmoyes";
        $dbPassword = "F!lmtrepid";
        $db = "tysonmoyes";

        $dbConn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $db);
        $this->dbConn = $dbConn;
        return $dbConn;
    }

    function queryDB($queryString) {
        return mysqli_query($this->getConnected(), $queryString);
    }

    public function close() {
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment and as others mention, return the connection foremost.

I personally think PDO would be a better option because parameterizing is really easy, but you are probably supposed to use `mysqli_` so I would rework your set up a bit. This is not tested, just take notes of differences:

**/classes/Database.php**

```
<?php
class Database
    {
        private static  $singleton,
                        $con;
        # I LIKE TO RETURN THE SAME INSTANCE OF A CLASS HERE, OPTIONAL
        public function __construct()
            {
                if(!(self::$singleton instanceof Database))
                    self::$singleton = $this;

                return self::$singleton;
            }
        # I LIKE TO STORE THE CONNECTIONS AND RETURN IT INSTEAD OF POSSIBLY
        # CREATING A NEW INSTANCE
        public function getConnected()
            {
                # IF THIS STATIC IS NOT A CONNECTION, MAKE ONE
                if(!(self::$con instanceof MySQLi))
                    self::$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
                # RETURN THE CONNECTION
                return self::$con;
            }

        public function query($sql)
            {
                return mysqli_query(self::$con, $sql);
            }

        public function close()
            {
                mysqli_close(self::$con);
            }
    }
```

**/config.php**

```
<?php
# I PERSONALLY LIKE TO USE A CONFIG (PREFS FILE) TO STORE MY DB INFO INCASE IT CHANGES
define('DB_HOST',"localhost");
define('DB_USER',"tysonmoyes");
define('DB_PASS',"F!lmtrepid");
define('DB_NAME',"tysonmoyes");
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
# I ALSO LIKE TO STORE PATH CONSTANTS SO IT'S AN EASY AND CONSISTANT WAY TO
# LOCATE/INCLUDE FILES
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('CLASS_DIR',ROOT_DIR.DS.'classes');
# START SESSION
session_start();
# USING AN AUTOLOADER IS A MUST ON CLASSES
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if(class_exists($class))
        return;
    # SHOULD RETURN A PATH LIKE:
    # /var/www/domain/httpdocs/myproject/classes/Database.php
    # WHEN CALLING $Database = new Database();
    $path = str_replace(DS.DS,DS,CLASS_DIR.DS.str_replace("\\",DS,$class)).'.php';
    # Presuming the file is named properly (and I have done the path right),
    # it would add the class file for you without using include anywhere.
    if(is_file($path))
        include_once($path);
});
```

**/classes/User.php**

```
<?php
class User
    {
        private $conn;
        # I WOULD SET ALL USER INFO TO AN ARRAY INSTEAD OF IN SEPARATE VARIABLES
        private $userData = array();

    # I MIGHT HINT AT TYPE HERE
    public function __construct(\Database $conn)
        {
            $this->conn = $conn;
        }

    public function createNewUser($username, $password)
        {
            $username = trim($username);
            $password =  trim($password);

            // Encrypt password
            $password = password_hash($password);

            // Check if username already exists
            # SQL INJECTION ISSUE HERE, YOU NEED TO BIND PARAMS HERE
            $checkSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
            $checkResult = $this->conn->query($checkSQL);

            if($checkResult->num_rows > 0) {
                $error = "true";
                $errorMessage = "This username has already been taken. Please try again";
            }
            else {
                # INJECTION ISSUE HERE
                $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES('$username', '$password')";
                //$insertResult = $this->conn->query($insertSQL);

                // Get the user ID
                $userID = $this->conn->getConnected()->insert_id;

                // Set the SESSION globals
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
            }
        }

        public function login($username, $password)
            {
                # YOU SHOULD NOT BE INJECTING HERE. I USE PDO, SO I WON'T
                # ATTEMPT A GOOD FIX HERE...BUT A FIX IS REQUIRED
                # YOU SHOULD ALSO NOT MATCH PASSWORD HERE, JUST USERNAME
                # USE password_verify() TO MATCH HASH
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
                $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
                $row = $this->conn->getConnected()->fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

                # DO A CHECK FIRST THAT THERE IS A ROW RETURNED FOR USERNAME (NOT SHOWN IN MY EXAMPLE...)
                # DO THE MATCH HERE
                $valid = password_verify($_POST['password'],$row['password']);

                if($valid) {
                    // Set Session Variables
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['userID'];

                     return true;
                }
            }

        public function isLoggedIn()
            {
                if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        public function redirect($url)
            {
                header("Location: $url");
                # YOU SHOULD EXIT HERE
                exit;
            }

        public function logout()
            {
                session_destroy();
                unset($_SESSION['username']);
                # YOU SHOULD PROBABLY REDIRECT HERE TO REFRESH THE SESSION
            }
    }
```

**/index.php**

```
# INCLUDE THE CONFIG ON ALL PAGES
include(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');

$Database = new Database();
$User = new User($Database);
```